# ARR with SSL offloading: app needs to know it was SSL

Tags: ssl, url-rewriting, iis-8.5, arr, offloading

I have set up a web farm with ARR, using SSL offloading.  Although the connection from ARR to the content site is proceeding with just HTTP, the application running on the site needs to know the original URL was HTTPS, so that links given in the result can be HTTPS. Can this be done?

I know I can *capture* the original HTTPS status as a new server variable (I'm using `HTTP-X-ORIGINAL-HTTPS`) using URL Rewrite on the ARR server. But how can I *restore* it to the content site using URL Rewrite? Obviously a **redirect** rule is not appropriate; a **none** action that sets server variables seems like it might be. I don't have an SSL binding on the content site.  Do I have to make my content application look for the `HTTP-X-ORIGINAL-HTTPS`? Seems ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I did -- I made the content application look for the request header `HTTPS`. (I have also switched from ARR to haproxy because haproxy gives me wildcard-bound TLS termination for free.)